dotTrace fails while activating cpp/cli type from c# app
dotTrace 2024.2.6 is failing on an enterprise application my company works on. It fails while activating cpp type. I created minimal example with similar structure. It fails if I leave ATL part in, if not dotTrace runs fine. I believe in the enterprise application the problem is not only with ATL. And it all worked fine until we have switched from net48 to net8.0.

Program.csproj
Program.cs
using System.Reflection;
var legacyDeploymentServerHostInstance = Assembly.LoadFrom("CppCli.dll").GetType("CppCli.CppCliType");
var baseType = Activator.CreateInstance(legacyDeploymentServerHostInstance!) as Library.CppCli.BaseType;
Console.WriteLine("Success");


Library.CppCli.csproj
BaseType.cs
namespace Library.CppCli {
    public interface BaseType : IDisposable {
    }
}


CppCli.vcxproj
CppCliType.h
namespace CppCli
{
    public ref class CppCliType : public Library::CppCli::BaseType
    {
    public:
         CppCliType();
         ~CppCliType();
    };
}

CppCliType.cpp
#include "CppCliType.h"
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <iostream>

namespace CppCli
{
    CppCliType::CppCliType()
    {
        CString aCString = CString(_T("A string"));
        std::cout << (LPCTSTR)aCString;
    }

    CppCliType::~CppCliType()
    {
        System::Text::Json::JsonSerializer::Serialize(this);
    }
}



The error I observe is

Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131506)
at System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.ProfilerBeginTransitionCallback(IntPtr, IntPtr, System.Object)
at .ATL.CSimpleStringT<wchar_t,0>.{ctor}(ATL.CSimpleStringT<wchar_t,0>, ATL.IAtlStringMgr)
at .ATL.CStringT<wchar_t,ATL::StrTraitATL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >.{ctor}(ATL.CStringT<wchar_t,ATL::StrTraitATL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t> > >, Char)
at CppCli.CppCliType..ctor()
at System.RuntimeType+ActivatorCache.CallConstructor(System.Object)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean, Boolean)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, Boolean, Boolean)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type, Boolean)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type)
at Program.$(System.String[])

EDIT: I've noticed the same behavior with ANTS Performance Profiler.

There is a somewhat similar bug report here.  That's where you need to file yours to get ahead.

@HansPassant dotTrace is from JetBrains, not from MS.

I've asked on dotTrace forum here. Got an answer that this is a known issue and I need to track this ticket.
